# Removing the :focus state from a link after modal window closes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to remove the :focus state from links that open a modal window once the modal is closed. Currently, and what seems like normal Bootstrap behavior is that the link maintains the focus until user clicks elsewhere on the page. I've tried;

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

  $('a').unbind('click', '.main-body');

})
```

Doesn't seem to do what I want. I tried throwing in an alert message, and while the alert is open the focus does go away but returns as soon as alert closes. Any ideas or help greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="main-body">Click to Enlarge</a></p>

  </div>

</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Some stuff goes here to read
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/jhottle/a5gcyfn5/10/)

Comment: That's pretty much the case with any anchor. Have you tried focusing elsewhere?

Comment: You can call `.blur()`.  Not sure you *should*, though, because accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your Javascript:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   setTimeout(function(){$('[data-target="#myModal"]').blur();}, 10);
});
```

It uses the event fired by bootstrap when the dialog closes. If you don't set a timeout, the link gets the focus again (not exactly sure why, but I guess the focus is set to the link right after the event is fired... Anyway).

Comment: To make the link lose it's focus, I changed your code a bit, replace the "data-target" bit with my link (a.main-body) and that seemed to do it. Thanks!!! that was making my client crazy.

Comment: Normally, the data-target attribute is set to the link opening the modal (like in your example), hence the selector. But your solution works as well. Happy to have been of some help, happy coding !